# How to change `time range of one day` in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

As the screenshot below, I want to get rid of the period from 0AM to 5AM which is useless to me. How can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For people arriving here after Google Labs was discontinued, see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114768/17465.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your calendar settings and then to Laboratory tab. The lab "Hide morning and night" does what you want.

Now your calendar would only show something if you actually have something planned within that window. There is a slider to adjust the times that are hidden.

Comment: "The first lab" isn't going to be very helpful when Google changes what's in the Labs.

Comment: I have enable `the lab`, ie. `Hide morning...`, but nothing happen. Can you give some screenshot of your calendar result?

Comment: Before: http://puu.sh/r30T, after: http://puu.sh/r31g

Comment: @Tschareck Lovley. I'm wondering why it didn't work for me...

Comment: @Tschareck It works for me now. I explain why in my answer so as to have image in the post. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately this feature fails when you try to hide an interval after midnight... say something like 2am-6am :-/

Comment: Google has discontinued Labs. It's possible to get this feature with a Chrome Extension: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121368/197505

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Tschareck, we use the google calendar lab "Hide morning and night".

> There is a slider to adjust the times that are hidden

which means it does NOT hide the time at first and add a slider for us to adjust the time as below screenshot.

[image]