# How to limit visible hours in new Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Until Google forced the new calendar on users, I was able to hide selected morning/night hours using a Labs feature. Is there any way to do the same in the new version, either through the calendar itself (preferable), a browser extension, CSS sheet, or another method?

Answer (score 12):

With the new (ca. 2017) Google Calendar, there is not a way to limit the number of visible hours. If that's a feature you think is missing, use the "feedback" tool to let them know. Otherwise, you'll need to seek out some third-party tool to do it for you, if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 6):

Since no one wanted to provide an actual solution, and somehow the standard Google response got accepted as the answer, this extension will allow you to change the working hours of Google Calendar, and more. This will work for the Material redesign of GCal.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-calendar-plus/mjelhipeelammmhpghkpigkdonihkakj

Comment: This needs access to read, and change data on accounts.google.com, and read browsing history. The other extension listed here doesn't, but it only works on weekly view.

Comment: So far as I can see, this extension can reduce the number of hours displayed, but it doesn't expand the calendar to fill the page.  :(  You just end up with more white space at the bottom.

Comment: both this extension and tone below Google Calendar Plus, work well

Answer (score 3):

There is a browser extension, [Google Calendar Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-calendar-plus/mjelhipeelammmhpghkpigkdonihkakj?hl=en), maintained for Chrome that does this well.

Opening the GCalPlus options via the puzzle icon you see, e.g.:

[image: GCalPlus options]

At the bottom you will see the **X** am to **Y** pm option which limits visibility on the hours.

Answer (score 1):

Google allows G Suite users to set ["Working Hours"](https://9to5google.com/2019/09/03/google-calendar-working-hours/) From General settings. However, normal GMail users do not have this same functionality. I've tried the extensions above and they do not see to be effective - all they do is force the "Collapsable Day" function that hides the hours when your browser window size is reduced. It isn't worth the unnecessary extension that [can hide malicious behavior](https://www.information-age.com/chrome-extensions-123478016/).

The best answer is to adapt to the current software structure and provide feedback to Google via the feedback form. This is what leads to UI development and updates.

[image]

Comment: The "working hours" doesn't seem to have any relationship to the question asked.  It doesn't affect what hours are displayed.  :(

Comment: In my experience with Google Workspace, adjusting the working hours changes what hours are displayed first which may be a solution to "hide selected morning/night hours" from the original question.

Comment: This no longer appears to have any effect on the hours displayed, if it once did.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Google Chrome extension which hides the morning section of the calendar, essentially doing what you ask.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-morning-in-calendar/oaikandahkibeihnampagmegnpfefhca/related?hl=en